# Collection view image loaded from document directory lags when scrolled

Tags: swift, scroll, uicollectionview, lag, uicollectionviewlayout

I am retrieving data from Document directory to populate collection view cell which contains an image and label.

While the data loads, but scrolling isnt smooth.

How to enable prefetching while retrieving image from document directory.

I get a unique name of image and then passing it in to load image function to populate the particular image in to cell from directory.

Comment: You aren't giving much information.  How many images are loaded into the collection view at what size?

Comment: Sorry, Hi, There are like 12 images each is of around 50kb to 700 kb.

Comment: you face issue because every time you make scroll up and down it go for set image again so scroll is not smooth

Comment: Any workaround to stop it fetching image if its filled already? 

I have tried prefetching , but not sure how to do it when loading from local storage, 

Sorry about that, I am kinda beginner to Swift